# Stringify JSON differently on each level

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

In order to hash (sha1) a JSON and to compare the resulting hash to a given one, I need a String which is exactly the same as the one that has been used to create the given hash.

Then, my stringified JSON must have different indentation for sub nodes of the JSON :

I want this js object :

```
{id:4,name:'patrick',roles:[{id:1,name:'admin'},{id:2,name:'author'}]}
```

to be stringified like that :

```
"{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "patrick",
    "roles": [
      {"id":1,"name":"admin"},
      {"id":2,"name":"author"}
    ]
}"
```

JSON.stringify(obj,null,4) gives me something very near from the solution but not exactly :

```
"{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "patrick",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "admin"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "author"
        }
    ]
}"
```

I'm trying with the second argument of JSON.stringify but can not reach my goal :'(

Comment: Another problem you may encounter is that the order of the object properties isn't guaranteed.

Comment: the given hash has been generated with the given json.
Does the json change during the transport ?

Comment: IMO, formatting should not be part of the JSON string, except when presenting it to be human-readable (in which case the original JSON should be formatted with a beautifier on the fly). Indentation and other whitespace should not affect what the JSON represents in _any_ way. My suggestion is that you should compare hashes on minified JSON, and not a formatted presentation.

Comment: Since json is just another way of representing values in a tree-like structure: perhaps deserializing and hashing objects would be one way to do it.

Comment: @Phebus40 it's not that the data changes. The process of deserializing/reserializing is not required to maintain object property order.